# Why custom form broke after the Gutenberg update?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm working with a child theme and before the Gutenburg project was released, my page/form was working.

The page would post to itself and if the criteria was all met, it'd hide the form and display a success message. Now you have to click the submit button, the form's opacity changes (best way I can describe it) but then the form comes back. The form fields are still populated so I click submit again and then the form will post. But now I no longer see the success (or error) message any more.

```
    <?php

    $response = "";

    //response messages
    $not_human       = "Please confirm you are human by clicking on the reCAPTCHA box.";
    $bad_date_range       = "The start date cannot be later than the end date. Please review your dates and submit again.";
    $missing_content = "Please provide all information being asked. Your name, phone number, and email address will only be used internally and will not be visible by the public.";
    $email_invalid   = "Please review your email. It does not appear to be formatted correctly.";

    //user posted variables
    $firstname = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['message_firstname'] ) );
    $lastname = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['message_lastname'] ) );
    $email = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['message_email'] ) );
    $phone = strip_tags( stripslashes( $_POST['message_phone'] ) );
    //function to generate response
    function generate_response($type, $message){
        global $response;
        var_dump($type);
        if($type == "success") {
            $response = $message;
            ?>
            <style>
                .hpwd_gs_success {display: block !important;};
            </style>
            <?php
        } else {
            $response = $message;
            ?>
            <style>
                .hpwd_gs_error {display: block !important;};
            </style>
            <?php
        }
    }
    function insertGSApplication( $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $my_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_junk';
        $my_form_data = array(
            'event_desc' => '<strong>Office Use Only:</strong><br/>' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname . '<br/>' . $email . '<br/>' . $phone );
        $wpdb->insert( $my_table_name, $my_form_data, array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        ));
        $event_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
        __insertGSApplication($event_id, $begin, $end);
    }
    function __insertGSApplication($event_id, $begin, $end) {
        global $wpdb;
        $my_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_junk_events';
        $group_id = 0;
        $format   = array( '%d', '%s', '%s', '%d' );
        $data = array(
                'occur_group_id' => $group_id
            );
        $result = $wpdb->insert( $my_table_name, $data, $format );
    }
    if(
        isset($_POST['submit']) &&
        !empty($_POST['submit']) 
    ) {
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            generate_response("error", $email . " " . $email_invalid);      // email validation failed
        }
        else {
            //validate presence of form fields **** need to also check for date and times; baby steps
            if(
                empty($firstname) ||
                empty($lastname) ||
                empty($phone)
            ){
                generate_response("error", $missing_content);               // missing some form data
            } else if(empty($reCAPTCHA)) {
                generate_response("error", $not_human);                         // missing captcha
            } else if($startdate_alt > $enddate_alt) {                      // enddate is before start date
                generate_response("error", $bad_date_range);
            } else {
            // human check (captcha start)
                $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$reCAPTCHA);
                $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);           // human check (captcha end)
                if($responseData->success) {                            // validating google's response on human check
                    //  save data
                    insertGSApplication( $firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone );

                    //send email per SendGrid documentation
                    $subject = 'GS Permit Application from ' . $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
                    $message = $firstname . " " . $lastname . " has submitted a GS appliction for:";
                    $message .= "\r\n\r\n";
                    $message .= $address;
                    $message .= "\r\n\r\n";
                    $message .= "Go to " . get_site_url() . "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-junk-manage&limit=reserved&sort=4&order=ASC to approve it";
                    $to = array('gs@domain.com');
                    $headers = new SendGrid\Email();
                    $headers->setFromName("NO REPLY")
                        ->setFrom("NOREPLY@domain.com")
                        ->setBcc("other@domain.com")
                        ->addCategory('GS');
                    $mail = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                    //  generate the reponse
                    generate_response("success",$message_saved);
                } else {
                    generate_response("error",$message_unsaved);
                }
            }
        }
    }

get_header();  

?>
<div id="main-content">

    <div class="container">
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
                <h1 class="entry-title main_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <div id="hpwd_row" class="et_pb_section  et_pb_section_1 et_section_regular">
                        <div class=" et_pb_row et_pb_row_1">
                            <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_4_4  et_pb_column_1 et-last-child">
                                <div class="et_pb_code et_pb_module  et_pb_code_0">
                                    <div class="et_pb_code_inner">
                                        <div id="formid" class="et_pb_module et_pb_contact_form_container clearfix  et_pb_contact_form_0" data-form_unique_num="0">
                                            <div class="et_pb_contact">

                                            <form id="hpwd_gs_frm" class="et_pb_contact_form clearfix" method="post" action="<?php get_site_url() ?>" autocomplete="false">
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_0 et_pb_contact_field_half" data-id="name" data-type="input" style="">
                                                    <label for="message_firstname" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">First Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="message_firstname" class="input" value="<?php echo $_POST['message_firstname']; ?>" name="message_firstname" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="input" data-original_id="name" placeholder="First Name">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_1 et_pb_contact_field_half et_pb_contact_field_last" data-id="lastname" data-type="input" style="">
                                                    <label for="message_lastname" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Last Name</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="message_lastname" class="input" value="<?php echo $_POST['message_lastname']; ?>" name="message_lastname" data-required_mark="required" data-field_type="input" data-original_id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                                    </p>
                                                    <p class="et_pb_contact_field et_pb_contact_field_3 et_pb_contact_field_half" data-id="telephoneno" data-type="input" style="">
                                                    <label for="phone_us" class="et_pb_contact_form_label">Phone Numer</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="phone_us" id="phone_us" value="<?php echo $_POST['message_phone']; ?>" name="message_phone" maxlength="14" placeholder="(999) 999-9999">
                                                    </p>

                                                    <p align="center">
                                                        <div align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="I have read and agree to the terms and conditions above" class="et_pb_contact_submit et_pb_button">I have read and agree to the terms and conditions above</button></div>
                                                    </p>

                                                    <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted" name="_wpnonce-et-pb-contact-form-submitted" value="e089401553"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/domain/contact-us-today/">

                                                </form>

                                            </div> <!-- .et_pb_code_inner -->
                                        </div>

                                    </div> <!-- .et_pb_code_inner -->
                                </div> <!-- .et_pb_code -->
                            </div> <!-- .et_pb_column -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/sandimas/assets/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" /> -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> -->
```

This is my first time to create a form without the use of a plugin - couldn't find a plugin that would do what I need so this approach was taken.

Comment: Sorry about the lower half of the formatting, I couldn't get it to format as I wanted. :(

Comment: Also, the code was trimmed down to be more "manageable" and to obfuscate the code some. Hopefully in doing that, I didn't actually break the code. :)

Comment: It appears the nonce was tripping me up due to bad syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress nonce had some bad syntax.